# Trying to use htaccess to add a query string to the URL as long as the URL contains a set of numbers?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

first time posting but this site has been a big help over the years. Anyway here is the situation. I've got a client with a WordPress site and it is integrated with a 3rd party platform that allows them to manage specific data that appears on the site. Certain pages, say an event detail page, have a numerical id in the url that is being generated automatically. What I'd like to do is add a query string to the end of any url that ends in a number (the ids are all 4 digits if that changes anything).

Example:

- `https://members.example.com/events` - main events listing page
- `https://members.example.com/events/details/name-of-event-1234` - event details page

What I'd like it to be:

```
https://members.examplesite.com/events/details/name-of-event-1234?clearcache=1
```

Basically there's some caching issues between the site and the 3rd party platform that is causing some display issues and after working on a few possible fixes with the developer of the platform, they suggested adding that query string to the end of all URLs that use their data on the site. Some I was able to do in the WordPress menu manager but pages like the above example are generated not set in the menu system.

The fine folks on the WordPress subreddit helped me get this far:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite if URL ends with /<any-string>-<number> and doesn't contain clearcache
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)clearcache=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ $1$2-$3?clearcache=1 [L,QSA]
```

It doesn't appear to be working though. I've never worked with regular expressions before, any assistance is greatly appreciated.

I'm happy to explain in greater detail how the integration works if further clarification will help.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> # Rewrite if URL ends with /<any-string>-<number> and doesn't contain clearcache
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)clearcache=1(&|$) [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*/)?([^/]+)-([0-9]+)$ $1$2-$3?clearcache=1 [L,QSA]
> ```

This would need to be an external redirect, as opposed to an internal rewrite, in order to "clear any caches". This rule must also be at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* any existing mod_rewrite directives.

This rule could also be simplified as I don't imagine this request could ever map to a physical file or directory. The regex can also be simplified as you don't need to capture all parts of the URL, you just need to assert that the last part matches the format `<any-string>-<number>`.

Try the following instead:

```
# Rewrite if URL ends with /<any-string>-<number> and doesn't contain clearcache
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)clearcache=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule (^|/)[\w-]+-\d+$ %{REQUEST_URI}?clearcache=1 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

Where `<any-string>` can contain any of the characters `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_` (underscore) or `-` (hyphen).

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect.

You don't need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive, as this already appears later in the file inside the WordPress code block.

HOWEVER, if you are hoping to clear client-side/browser caches with this then it's not going to have the desired result, since the request won't reach the server in order to append the `clearcache=1` URL parameter. The rule in `.htaccess` only changes the URL once the initial request for the non-clearcache URL has reached the server.

Comment: Thank you, I've replaced what I had with your suggestion at the top of the file. I'll keep my eye on the site and see if it achieves the desired end result.

Comment: Looks like it has to be client-side. I just checked it and it's still acting up. I'll keep digging and see what I can find. From your answer, do you mean that expression won't do it or that using the `.htaccess` isn't the right solution in this case?

Comment: @Justin So, there is no redirect? Is the request reaching your server? "using the `.htaccess` isn't the right solution" - Well, it's unclear what "some caching issues between the site and the 3rd party platform" means exactly. If the issue is a client-side/browser (or proxy?) cache then `.htaccess` is not the right solution since the request does not reach your server - but in that case there is no solution, except wait for the client-side cache to expire (or manually clear it) or _manually_ append `clearcache=1` to the request the browser makes (which effectively just bypasses the cache).

Comment: As far as I can tell it is reaching but it seems to be a client side issue. Basically WordPress and the integration are both trying to load the header of the website which means the logo and menu displays twice at the top of the page before the content. Once you clear the cache it resolves the issue and displays properly. I'll reach out to the dev and see if there's anything else we can try.